# What are the PowerShell “special” variables and characters

Tags: variables, powershell, shorthand

This question is to help clear up some confusion I have with variables in PowerShell. I'm familiar with the concept of creating a variable and assigning it a value.. for example, in SharePoint, you would do this:  `$spsite = http://site`

Yet, there are a lot of variables that come from PowerShell that can be used in various ways.

For example, if I set a site collection in a variable `$spsite` (like I did above), I can do a foreach loop on it and iterate through each web site..

`foreach ($web in $spsite)`

In another example, I see something like this

```
$a = 5
$b = 6
$c = 7
$d = $a,$b,$c

Foreach ($i in $d)
{ $i + 5}
```

In both cases, I have not assigned a value to $i or $web.. yet they have some kind of meaning or value. I get that $web is each website in a site collection. But how does PowerShell know this? It just does?

Can someone explain this and/or send me a link to where this is explained?

Also is there a list of all these special variables and special characters (shortcuts) in PowerShell.. for example, I believe % is the foreach-object cmdlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$i` and `$web` aren't special variables. They are just popular names that people reuse. The name of the current object in a `foreach`-loop is defined by you.

Ex:

```
#Creating a simple array for the demonstration
$MyArrayOfAwesomeObjects = 1,2,3

foreach ($ThisVariableIsAwesome in $MyArrayOfAwesomeObjects) {

    #Here, $ThisVariableIsAwesome is the current object, and we can call methods on it.
    $ThisVariableIsAwesome.GetType()

}

IsPublic IsSerial Name  BaseType
-------- -------- ----  --------
True     True     Int32 System.ValueType
True     True     Int32 System.ValueType
True     True     Int32 System.ValueType
```

As for `%` -> `Foreach-Object`, that is just an alias. You can view all aliases with `Get-Alias`

Comment: Oh ok.  So for the example in my original post, I could do something like: `foreach ($myawesomeweb in $spsite)` and it would do the same thing?  ... and $i is basically saying "for each variable in my array"?  Thanks for the Get-Alias cmdlet.

Comment: Yes. The reason so many people uses `$i` and not `$whatever` is because it stands for `index`.

Comment: Well, technically it is an item from the collection and not an index.  But you could think of `$i` as short for `$item`. :-)

Comment: Probably more correct. I was thinking about how the `i` originated, and that may aswell have been because of item. The first times I saw it, it was as an index/counter while looping through an array (`$array[$i]`) Hehe :)